# C to MIPS translation

Tags: c, mips, spim

Trying to convert this c code into MIPS and run it in SPIM.

```
int A[100], B[100];
for(i=1; i<100; 1++){
A[i] = A[i-1] + B[i];
}
```

So far this is what I have.

```
    # comments are delimted by has marks

.data
A:   .word  0:100        # array of 12 integers
B:   .word  0:100        # array of 12 integers


.text
main:
    li $v0, 1       # load the value "1" into register $v0
    li $t0, 1       # load the value "1" into register $t0
    li $t1, 100     # load the value "100" into register $t1
    blt $t0, $t1, loop # branches to Loop if $t0 < 100
    la $t9, B
    la $t8, A

loop:
    sll $t0, $t0, 2
    add $t2, $t9, $t0 
    lw $s4, 0($t9)
    add $t3, $t0, -1
    add $t4, $t8, $t3
    lw $s5, 0($t4)
    add $t5, $t2, $s5
    add $t6, $s0, $t0
    sw $t7, 0($t5)
    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    li $v0, 1 # system call for print_int
    move $a0, $t0 # the sum to print
    syscall # print the sum
```

When running in SPIM I get the following errors:

```
Exception occurred at PC=0x00400040
  Bad address in data/stack read: 0x00000004
Exception occurred at PC=0x0040004c
  Unaligned address in inst/data fetch: 0x00000003
Exception occurred at PC=0x00400058
  Bad address in data/stack read: 0x00000000
Attempt to execute non-instruction at 0x0040006c
```

Some direction would be nice. Thanks

Comment: Why not compile first and optimize the result?

Comment: What is MIPS? Can't find in wikipdia

Comment: Alon: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture

Comment: Ouch, are we so old that we now have programmers in our midst that never heard of MIPS? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are branching to `loop` (`blt $t0, $t1, loop`) before you initialize the pointers to `A` and `B`. You need to move the `blt $t0, $t1, loop` to the end of your code, not have it at the beginning.

I hate to do this, but there are too many things wrong to list them all. Try this:

```
.data 
A:   .word  0:100        # array of 100 integers 
B:   .word  0:100        # array of 100 integers 


.text 
main: 
    li $t0, 4       # load the value "1" into register $t0 
    li $t1, 400     # load the value "100" into register $t1 
    la $t9, B 
    la $t8, A 

loop: 
    add $t2, $t9, $t0  # $t2 = B + i
    lw $s4, 0($t9)     # $s4 = B[i]
    add $t3, $t0, -4   # $t3 = i - 1
    add $t4, $t8, $t3  # $t4 = A + i - 1
    lw $s5, 0($t4)     # $s5 = A[i - 1]
    add $t5, $t8, $t0  # $t5 = A + i
    add $t6, $s4, $s5  # $t6 = B[i] + A[i - 1]
    sw $t6, 0($t5)     # A[i] = $t6
    addi $t0, $t0, 4   # i++

    li $v0, 1 # system call for print_int 
    move $a0, $t6 # the sum to print 
    syscall # print the sum

    blt $t0, $t1, loop # branches to Loop if $t0 < 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Right off the bat, s1 and s2 should be initialized to the stack-based (I assume) address of your arrays.

Comment: I have initialized the arrays properly now (I think). Im getting the smae errors, looks like with the load word command is being executed.